# difference between 'if x not in dict' and 'if not x in dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was testing some code where i wanted to print if x is in dictionary or not.

my code was

```
temp_dict = {...}
if x not in temp_dict:
    # Do something
    pass
```

However this didn't work, even though x wasn't present in `temp_dict` the `if` wasn't evaluated to True and its body wasn't executed (of course).

When I changed it to

```
temp_dict = {...}
if not x in temp_dict:
    # Do something
    pass
```

it worked!

Can somebody please explain the difference?

Comment: There's no difference. You must have changed something else without noticing.

Comment: @JohnColeman `... not in ...` is valid in Python

Comment: @JohnColeman: That would be true, except that Python actually has a `not in` operator that gets translated to a combination of `not` and `in`.

Comment: (In the bytecode, `not in` is its own opcode, and `not x in y` actually gets compiled to use the `not in` opcode, but in execution, the `not in` operator applies `in` and then `not`s the result.)

Comment: In what way did it "not work"?